# changing external_uri for private cloud setup

Tags: cloud, installation, private, cloud-foundry

I am trying to setup a local/private cloud with cloudfoundry, and by that I need a local domain set as my target url (and not .vcap / .cloudfoundry.com).
I read somewhere here on the forum that by changing the external_uri value in cloud_controller.yml we can achieve this. 
(vcap/cloud_controller/config/cloud_controller.yml)

But after I change the value in the file, what do I need to restart? I tried reapplying the configuration option or restarting the vm (i am running this on vmware fusion), but that reset back to the old config value.

Any help/guide on setting up private cloud with cloudfoundry would be great!

Comment: Posting your OSS question at https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/vcap-dev is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the comment, posting your OSS question at the [VCAP-DEV google group](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev) is your best bet.